# How to change the order in natbib´s short citation?

Tags: citing, natbib

I´m using `natbib` with the `apalike` style.
When using the short citation

```
\citet[p. 22]{Testauthor98}
```

it shows me

> Testauthor (1998, p. 22)

What do i have to do/change in order to get the following result?

> Testauthor (1998), p. 22

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write (using `~` for a non-breaking space)

```
\citet{Testauthor98}, p.~22
```

(Obviously, this solution is not suited for reformatting large existing documents without changing the document body.)

Comment: Ah, of course. That simple.